# Encoded java is not giving the same result like the normal URL

Tags: java, rest, api, url, encoding

Hello so i am trying to get a json object using GET method form an URL using A rest API so when i send the normal URL :

```
https://hostname/fil/rest/api/2/search?jql=project= "Station Server" AND status != Done AND assignee = "User New" ORDER BY priority DESC&maxResults=2
```

lets say it return a json object with 2 element inside

this give me the result i want but when i Encode it so i can use it inside my java code it give me another result it give a json object with 25000 element inside

This is the encoded URL :

```
https://hostname/fil/rest/api/2/search?jql%3Dproject%3D%20%22Station%20Server%22%20AND%20status%20%21%3D%20Done%20AND%20assignee%20%3D%20%22User%20New%22%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC%26maxResults%3D2
```

I test it inside the java code and inside google rest API its gives me the same result :

```
String url2 = "https://jira/jira/rest/api/2/search?";
String toencode = "jql=project= \"Station server\" AND status != Done AND assignee = \"User New\" ORDER BY priority DESC&maxResults=2";

String url3 = URLEncoder.encode(toencode,"UTF-8").replaceAll("\\+", "%20");
String url = url2 + url3;
```

and after that i send the get request using url 
What am i doing wrong please ?

Comment: no its not the same thing at all !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you encode the '=' after jql.

That particular '=' needs to be part of the URL, so the server interprets it properly as a query parameter. By encoding it, you basically sent a request for all results, as the server interprets this as a search without a jql query.

Comment: exactly i am getting all the results thats why i dont understand why ! you mean i put String url2 = "https://jira/jira/rest/api/2/search?jql="; and take off this from the second URL ?